# why css borders not shown carefully?

Tags: image, css, border, smoothing

i coded a arrow with css.
the code

```
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 0 25px 4px ;
border-color: transparent transparent transparent #cacaca;
```

The shot :

[image]
[ایگل دیزاین](http://eagle-design.ir/) [طراحی سایت](http://eagle-design.ir/)

the slash line is not a smooth line.

whats your idea ?

Comment: please, create a snippet (with your html + css code) so we can help you better

Comment: The arrow ratio  you used approximately (6:1) 25px height to 4px width will give you uneven line.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it would not be smooth, could be that you may need to specify the borders long hand.

e.g. `border-top: 20px solid transparent`

css tricks has a good article on [css triangles](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
border-top: 25px solid $pink;
border-right: 50px inset transparent;
border-left: 50px inset transparent;
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TMP7H/495/)**